# Can I tell after already showing?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, style, technique

When writing fiction, I try to adhere to the rule of showing rather than telling. That said, is it ok to tell after already showing?
For example, I have a character already shown to be insecure. Is it ok to later say something along the lines of, “...the look of recognition in the darkened pits that are his mother’s eyes, serves only to add to the young boy’s insecurities...”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what the point of view character would notice.  It is perfectly normal for someone to notice things in detail the first time, and less with each time after, except for changes.  So indicating it's as before is normal.

If it's an omniscient narrator without a point of view character, choose a consistent voice as if it were a character.